# Efficiency. DataTable or Worksheet? Using interop C#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, interop

I am working on a project and I am looking for **efficiency**, I have a **DataTable that I convert in a excel file and I can treat using Interop**. What I am looking for in this project is to add all the values that a father has. For example, the father of the values in red blood cells are "*COSC-1218-SIT41SCH*". I have to do this with thousands of rows ...

[image]

So, when I try to do it iterating over *DataTable* or *Worksheet*, I have to wait like 10-25 minutes and that's a lot for me. *Is there another way to get these values*? Any recommendation?
If you want to see the code, I can publish it.

This is my code

```
for (int j = 1; j <= usedRange.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= usedRange.Columns.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (Convert.ToString(usedRange.Cells[j, i].Value) == "Peso Total")
                    {
                        colPT = i;
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToString(usedRange.Cells[j, i].Value) == "Peso Unitario")
                    {
                        colPU = i;
                        filaPU = j;
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToString(usedRange.Cells[j, i].Value) == "Cantidad Total")
                    {
                        colCantidadTotal = i;
                    }
                    if (j > 1)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" Obteniendo nivel actual ... ");
                        //almaceno en lact el nivel de la celda actual
                        lact = Convert.ToInt32(usedRange.Cells[j,posNivel2].Value());
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" Nivel actual obtenido, es: " + lact);
                    }
                    //almaceno el valor de la celda actual en valCel
                    valCel = Convert.ToString(usedRange.Cells[j, i].Value);

                    //Obtengo la dirección de la celda actual, por ejemplo Q7
                    dirCelda = CellAddress(Worksheet, j, i);

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("******* Exportando a Excel, el valor actual de la celda es: | info pruebas ValCell contiene -> " + valCel + " y la dirección es: " + rng.Address + " la j fila es: " + j + " y la i columna es: " + i + " -------- " + dirCelda + " el límite de columnas es : " + usedRange.Columns.Count + " y de filas es: " + usedRange.Rows.Count);

                    xz = Convert.ToString(usedRange.Cells[j+1,posNivel2].Value);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" Probaaaaaaaaando, posnivel es: " + posNivel2 + " y xz contiene: " + xz);

                    //bucle Peso Total, j diferente a 1 para no acceder a la cabecera y no sobrepasar las filas con j+1
                    if (j!=1 && j + 1 < usedRange.Rows.Count)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" === CheckPnt 0: ");
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(usedRange.Cells[j + 1,posNivel2].Value) < usedRange.Rows.Count)
                        {
                            //Obtengo el nivel de la siguiente fila
                            levelmas = Convert.ToInt32(usedRange.Cells[j + 1,posNivel2].Value);
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" === CheckPnt 1, levelactual es: " + lact + " levelmas:" + levelmas + " J es:" + j + " y RowCounts es " + usedRange.Rows.Count);
                        }
                        //si el nivel actual más 1 es igual al nivel de la fila siguiente y no se supera el límite de filas
                        if ((lact + 1) == levelmas && j + 1 < usedRange.Rows.Count)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" === CheckPnt 2: ");
                            dirCelda = CellAddress(Worksheet, j, i);
                            formulaPadre = "=(";
                            int iterador = j + 1;
                            bool encontr = false;
                            //se crea iterador y se recorren las filas hasta que se encuentre una del mismo nivel
                            while (iterador < usedRange.Rows.Count && !encontr)
                            {
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" === Bucle While");
                                //si la siguiente fila tiene un nivel más que el padre se añade la celda
                                if ((lact + 1) == Convert.ToInt32(usedRange.Cells[iterador,posNivel2].Value))
                                {
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" === CheckPnt 3: ");
                                    //si quiero quitar el primer + evaluar si es el primero
                                    formulaPadre = formulaPadre + "+" + CellAddress(Worksheet, iterador, colPT); // getCellNamev2(iterador, colPT);
                                }
                                //si se encuentra una fila con el mismo nivel se para y se añade el paréntesis final
                                if ((lact + 1) > Convert.ToInt32(usedRange.Cells[iterador,posNivel2].Value) || iterador + 1 == RowsCount)
                                {
                                    formulaPadre = formulaPadre + ")";
                                    encontr = true;
                                    //si encontrado encontes almaceno la fórmula en la columna peso total y reinicio fórmula
                                    //colPT es columna Peso Total
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" Fin hijos se añade el último paréntesis y la fórmula es: " + formulaPadre);
                                    usedRange.Cells[j, colPT] = formulaPadre;
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cells de Fórmula Padre contine: " + Cells[j,colPT].ToString());
                                    formulaPadre = "";

                                }
                                iterador++;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Si no es padre se múltiplica cantidad x Peso Unitario
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" NO es padre, aplico la otra fórmula");
                            //celdaPesoTotal = getCellNamev2(j, i);
                            celdaCantidad = CellAddress(Worksheet, j, colCantidadTotal); //getCellNamev2(j, colCantidadTotal);

                            celdaPesoUnitario = CellAddress(Worksheet, j, colPU); //getCellNamev2(filaPU, colPU);
                            formulaHijo = "=" + celdaCantidad + "*" + celdaPesoUnitario;
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" -__--__-----> La fórmula del Peso Total para el level 2 es: " + formulaHijo);
                            usedRange.Cells[j, colPT] = formulaHijo;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Show your code.
My initial suggestion is to read the excel file and convert it to an object list (https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader), then iterate over the object list. When you need to update the excel, use range instead of per cell.

Comment: @rjs123431 thank you for your answer. Post edited with the code. I will take a look of ExcelDataReader!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a List<> for each column and iterate trough the list and simply check if your list element x with the values of nivel2 you want to select has your desired value at the same index.

You can convert your DataTable to a list with something like

```
List<string> list = dtusers.AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(r=> r.Field<string>("ColumnName"))
                           .ToList();
```

But there are also a lot of other possibilities to convert the DataTable to a list.

Comment: Could be a good idea! But the idea is put the value in a excel cell, so is a good idea work with a datatable, excel worksheet and a list?

Comment: Let me understand your final goal. You have a data table with  the columns like shown above and you only want to insert values to the excel sheet where for example there is an value in nivel2, nivel1 and nivel0 and sort out rows where there is only a value in nivel1 and nivel0 but no value in nivel2?